# Why PHP keeps resetting the array pointer?

Tags: php, arrays

So I spent 2 hours trying to figure this out, minimizing the code as much as possible to isolate the problem, yet I can't figure this out.

So I have this code:

```
$arr['key']['name'] = array("one", "two", "three");

$counter = 0;
do
{
    $cur = current($arr);

    $k = key($arr['key']['name']);
    next($arr['key']['name']);
}while($k !== null);
```

This is a never ending loop. For some reason, after going through all the $arr['key']['name'] values, key() instead of returning NULL, goes back to 0 again. Removing $cur = current($arr); however solves that problem. [According to php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php), `current()` doesn't affect the array pointer at all. Now I know that copying an array will reset its pointer but there's no copying going on and if there was $k would constantly be zero instead of going from 0 to 2 and then resetting back to 0.

Comment: You'd need `$cur = current($arr['key']['name']);` if you're doing `next($arr['key']['name']);`.

Comment: Because then I would get the current element of $arr['key']['name'] instead of a the current element of $arr which is $arr['key'] :)

Comment: This seems like something undocumented/bug. I rewrote "$cur = current($arr);" to "current($arr);" and the loop ended all right. Or I replaced "$arr['key']['name']" with "$arr['name']" and the loop ended all right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`current()` *doesn't* move the array pointer for the array you use it on, but you're using it on *different arrays*. It is resetting the pointer for the *nested* arrays.

Comment: How come? It doesn't make sense and it isn't mentioned anywhere in the current()'s manual.

Comment: Probably because no one ever expected it to be used this way.

Comment: Yes but if it really does reset the pointer for the nested arrays, why doesn't it do so on every iteration when current() runs but only after the whole $arr['key']['name'] array has been traversed?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do it this way ?

**Code :**

```
foreach ($arr['key']['name'] as $k)
{
    // do something with $k

}
```

Comment: Because I don't need to access all the elements at one run, I just made that small example to demonstrate the problem, in my real code it is not a loop :)